# Does this continued fraction have a name?

Tags: terminology, continued-fractions, constants

$1/(2+1/(3+1/(5+...) = [0; 2,3,5,...p_{\infty}] \approx 0.432332$

Does this constant have a name? What is it called? It does appear to converge from my initial calculations, and I'm surprised that I can't easily find anything for the infinite continued fraction of the primes.

Comment: You can find some connection about the constant there. https://oeis.org/A063083

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Continued fraction involving Fibonacci sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2904226/continued-fraction-involving-fibonacci-sequence)

Comment: I think the numbers OP is referencing are primes, not Fibonacci numbers, based on the $p_\infty$

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What is the sequence?  primes?  Fibonacci numbers?  something else entirely?  Why do you expect that it *should* have a name?  What motivates the question?

Comment: Yes, it is the primes. I thought the $p_{\infty}$ communicated that but I have clarified it in the edit. I'm honestly surprised that I can't find much of anything regarding it

Comment: and wouldn’t the Fibonacci sequence have $1$s before $2,3,5,...$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63865/a-continued-fraction-involving-prime-numbers

Comment: While the proposed duplicate question is certainly related, it seems clear to me that this question is asking (in the title and in the body) for a name for the constant, while the proposed duplicate is asking for its value

Comment: Is it known whether this number is transcendental ?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Generally speaking, "What is [x] called?" is not a good question for Math SE, unless the asker can suggest a good reason why they believe that an object ought to have been named.  I also believe that the linked question answers this question, as one would imagine that *if* some constant has a commonly used appellation, *then* the paper on arXiv would likely refer to such a designation.  While it is hard to prove a negative, the linked Q&A seems to address the question here by implication.